# Node.js will not update on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, nodejs

I've tried everything I know of and Googled this as well. I upgraded Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10 using Software Update. I then added the 13.x repository for Node.js and installed it.

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

I then did `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`. Node.js installed at 13.0.1 and when I try to update to 13.2, I get "nodejs is already the newest version" at 13.0.1.

Am I doing something wrong? I really need the latest 13.2.

Thanks!

Comment: At this time there is only 13.0.1 in official node repo. You can use nvm for install latest version of node.js.

Answer (score 1):

stop using the apt node repo's, they are waaaay out of date and will never catchup, worst is version incompatibilies on upgrades! Use NVM instead for installing node -

- git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
- run install.sh
- source ~/.profile to initialise the nvm vars set in home profile
- nvm ls-remote to list node versions available
- nvm install your-node-version
- nvm use your-node-version

Answer (score 0):

In recent Ubuntu versions, in some cases you can use snap instead of apt to get some packages.

In this case you might be in luck, because nodejs does provide snap packages for all major releases, and even the development version. So, to get latest nodejs, you can do the following:

1. Execute the following, according to the instructions at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#snap-packages:

   ```
   sudo snap install node --classic --channel=13
   ```

   (You can even choose `--channel=edge` to go beyond latest release.)

   (And you can even switch versions if you find that 13 doesn't work for you, for example to go to 12 run: `sudo snap refresh node --channel=12`.)
2. Uninstall whatever node/npm you installed via apt or otherwise.

   This step is usually necessary because `/snap/bin` folder is later in `$PATH` than system folders which apt touches. If you have custom setup in which `$PATH` doesn't follow this rule, step 2 might not be necessary.